# SQL Server Login and database user: why no db role?

Tags: sql-server

I have a server login myuser and the mapped to it database user myuser.
The db user myuser has a db role:  mydbrole.
I can see it executing the query:

```
SELECT  dbo.sysusers.uid, dbo.sysusers.name,IS_MEMBER(dbo.sysusers.name) as ismemeber
FROM    dbo.sysusers 
WHERE dbo.sysusers.issqlrole = 1 
AND IS_MEMBER(dbo.sysusers.name)=1
```

Then I add the server role 'sysadmin' to the login 'myuser' and the same query does not show that this user has a db role 'mydbrole' anymore. If I remove the 'sysadmin' from the login then all is ok.
Where is my error? What is incorrect?

Comment: `sysadmin` role members are implicitly mapped to the `dbo` user in all databases. User role memberships are irrelevant for `sysadmin` role members because permissions are not checked.

Comment: Thnx Dan. Please add as the answer and I mark it. Is the 'sysadmin' only one such specific server role for login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Members of the `sysadmin` server role are implicitly mapped to the `dbo` user in all databases. User role memberships are irrelevant for `sysadmin` role members because permissions are not checked.